# Vue include child component into parent slot

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on the tabs component in vue similar to the vertical navbar on the left and tab content on the right. My tabs titles have icons and I'm trying to use `<slot>` to put different icons in each tab title.

**Blade template:**

```
<tabs>
   <tab name="one" :selected="true">
      <svg>icon 1</svg>
   </tab>
   <tab name="two">
      <svg>icon 2</svg>
   </tab>
   <tab name="three">
      <svg>icon 3</svg>
   </tab>
<tabs>
```

**Tabs.vue**

```
<template>
    <ul class="my-class" role="tablist">
        <li v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
            <a>
                // here I want to place my icon defined in my blade view
                <slot></slot> // this doesn't work and it is showing 0 items in tab array
                <span>{{ tab.name }}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <slot></slot>
        // if placed here it works and it is showing 3 items in tab array
        // but icon's are placed under all 3 li elemets
    </ul>
</template>
```

**Tab.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have already tried a lot of different combinations, but no one worked and it is hard to know what's going on as there are no error messages. I'm not experienced in vue and I'm trying to check vue documentations but there must be something that escapes me or something that I'm not getting.

Could someone advise me where is the error or how should I rewrite my code?